# Convert SASS math expression to LESS

Tags: css, for-loop, express, sass, less

I have SASS code generating CSS classes inside it and that is working well. It has for loop and simple math expression.

I wanted to convert it into LESS but I can't complete it myself. Please look at the code below.

How can I covert this into LESS code as SASS was doing?

```
@for $i from 1 through (($point-count + 1) / 2) {
    &:nth-of-type(#{$i}) {
        transform: rotate(360deg / $point-count * ($i - 1));
    }

    &:nth-of-type(#{$i + $point-count / 2}) {
        transform: rotate(180deg + 360deg / $point-count * ($i - 1));
    }

    &:nth-of-type(#{$i}), &:nth-of-type(#{$i + $point-count / 2}) {
        &:before {
            animation-delay: - $spin-animation-time + ($spin-animation-time / $point-count * 2 * ($i - 1));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you code a simple [loop](http://lesscss.org/features/#loops-feature) in LESS? Manage interpolation of variables (outside of a loop to begin with)?

Answer (score 0):

```
.loop(@i) when (@i < (@point-count + 1) / 2) {
    .loop((@i + 1));

    &:nth-of-type(@{i}) {
        transform: rotate(360deg / @point-count * (@i - 1));
    }

    @index: @i + @point-count / 2;

    &:nth-of-type(@{index}) {
        transform: rotate(180deg + 360deg / @point-count * (@i - 1));
    }

    &:nth-of-type(@{i}),
    &:nth-of-type(@{index}) {
        &:before {
            animation-delay: - @spin-animation-time + (@spin-animation-time / @point-count * 2 * (@i - 1));
        }
    }
}

.loop(1)
```